# Coldfusion and Foundation 5 - will it work?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a big existing website (hundreds of dynamic pages) built in Coldfusion - we don't CF for any of the display stuff, that's just css and html.

We're about to implement a new front end design and it has been suggested that we use the Foundation 5 framework for the html and css - I don't have any experience with using frameworks and can't get my head around what the Foundation 5 framework is and if it'll get in the way of coldfusion (or vice versa)

Does anyone have any information that will help me gain an understanding as to what the framework actually does please /how it'd integrate with CF?

Thanks ever so much.

Nick

Comment: While a good question, it does not really fit StackOverflow. Take a look at the help section for asking questions - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foundation (or bootstrap) will be completely independent of the ColdFusion backend. They're simply separate technologies.

Foundation is a CSS framework - it doesn't have any serverside components (unless you count things like grunt + various ways of custom building the result).